# How would I assign a variable that contains a string to another variable that contains a string?

Tags: c

Just like the title says, I'm trying to see if I could assign a variable that contains a string to another variable that contains a string.

For example:

```
printf("Enter word to search in file: ");
scanf("%s", word);
word = words;
```

In this case, the string in `word` would be assigned to the string in `words`.

Comment: You've not shown how either `word` or `words` is defined. That's crucial information, though. You need to know whether there is anything special to be done with the 'old' data pointed at by `word`. If it is a local array, you don't have to release it; if it is a pointer to space allocated with `malloc()`, you probably need to free it. If you have a simple array, you have to use `strcpy()`. If you are using dynamic memory allocation, you may be able to use a simple pointer assignment.  If the `word` space is a function parameter, you have to define what the function doing the reading expects.

Comment: You also have to worry about overflows — how much space does `word` point at?  You've not limited the length of the string read via `scanf()`, so you are vulnerable to buffer overflow.  (See: [How to prevent `scanf()` causing a buffer overflow in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621394/15168)). And you need to know ensure that `words` provides enough space too — but how you do that depends on how `words` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `word` and `words` are `char *` then assigning `words` to `word` merely means both pointers are pointing to the same bit of memory.

If you wish to treat them as separate strings, you must use a function like [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) or [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy), and ensure `word` points to a separate block of valid memory you can copy *into*.

E.g.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char original[100];
    char copy[100];

    if (scanf("%99s", original) == 1) {
        strcpy(copy, original);
    }

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would recommend strdup(), which does exactly what is required, if using dynamic allocation.

Comment: I did consider using that, but that's new enough in terms of C standards that I felt it best to go with tried and true.

Comment: POSIX has defined [`strdup()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) since "forever" (not later than POSIX 1997, possibly earlier, but it wasn't in POSIX.1 1990 or POSIX.2 1992).  POSIX defines [`strndup()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strndup.html) too, but that is more recent (POSIX 2008).  The C standard up to and including C17 does not define `strdup()` or `strndup()`; in C23, `strdup()` and `strndup()` will finally be a part of standard C.